# Pull a SQL field with or without a space

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I would like to run the following queries as one query.  My goal is to pull all rows where the Store field = Best Buy or BestBuy, not pulling the same row twice.  Is there a way to do this one swoop?

```
Insert Into dbo.X WHERE Store = 'Best Buy';
Insert Into dbo.X WHERE Store = 'BestBuy';
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question right, You want to "pull" the information out of SQL. `INSERT` inserts data into the database. You want to `SELECT` the data.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.X WHERE Store = 'Best Buy' OR Store = 'BestBuy';
```

Furthermore, I am assuming you want to `SELECT` the entire row by using the `*`. You can specify which columns to pulls as well like this.

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM dbo.X WHERE Store = 'Best Buy' OR Store = 'BestBuy';
```

Comment: @ Wesley - Thanks.  Does the same apply for "Like."  For example,     WHERE Store LIKE '%Best Buy%' OR '%BestBuy%' ?

Comment: @HypeZJ `WHERE Store LIKE '%Best Buy%' OR Store LIKE '%BestBuy%'`

Comment: Not exactly. If you use `WHERE Store =` you will find exactly what you search for. With `LIKE`, the `%` acts as an "any" character. So `WHERE Store LIKE '%Best Buy%' Will find both "Best Buy" as well as "John Smith's Best Buy".

Comment: Would `WHERE Store LIKE '%Best%Buy%'` be a shorter solution?

Comment: No. `WHERE Store LIKE '%Best%Buy%'` would return answers like "Best Software Buy". If your are looking for an exact value, you ought to use `=` over `LIKE` to prevent similar results that are not exactly correct.

Comment: Although it's perhaps worth noting that with regular expressions one could do `WHERE Store RLIKE '^Best ?Buy$'` to match both `'BestBuy'` and `'Best Buy'` but nothing else (note that it's case insensitive unless you're using binary strings).

Answer (score 0):

Your queries are not syntactically correct.  I could assume that you mean:

```
select *
Into dbo.X
WHERE Store in ('Best Buy', 'BestBuy');
```

But you could also express this as:

```
select *
Into dbo.X
WHERE Store like 'Best%Buy';
```

The `'%'` can match no characters as well as a space.  But this would also match `Best IN THE NATION Buy`.